# I have an issue in jolt transformation. While transforming I need as expected output but getting different one

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am not able to transform the jolt properly using jolt spec. Thanks in photos array elements can be any like in above two are there, so it can be 3 or 4 or 5 any.

My jolt spec:

**Input JSON** :

```json
{
  "Entity": {
    "card": {
      "name": "RAM",
      "lastName": "ABU"
    },
    "Photos": [
      {
        "Id": "327703",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 1",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327703/photo.jpg"
      },
      {
        "Id": "327704",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 2",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327704/photo.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Jolt Spec** :

```json
[  
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Entity": {
        "card": {
          "name": "Photos[0].no",
          "lastName": "Photos[0].caption2."
        },
        "Photos": {
          "*": {
            "Id": "Photos[&1].no",
            "Caption": "Photos[&1].caption2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current output** :

```json
{
  "Photos" : [ {
    "no" : [ "RAM", "327703" ],
    "caption2" : [ "ABU", "TEST>> photo 1" ]
  }, {
    "no" : "327704",
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 2"
  } ]
}
```

**Expected output** :

```json
{
  "Photos" : [
    {
     "no" : "Ram",
    "caption2" : "ABU"
    },
   {
    "no" : "327703" ,
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 1" 
   },
    {
    "no" : "327704",
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 2"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that i have updated expected output and current output

Comment: in input JSON Photos array can have any no of elements , they are dynamic in nature.
eg
 "Photos": [
      {
        "Id": "327703",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 1",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327703/photo.jpg"
      },
      {
        "Id": "327704",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 2",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327704/photo.jpg"
      },
.....etc
    ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a shift transformation spec which will rearrange the desired elements to remain as two individual arrays nested within an object tagged `Photos`, and then put them into their respective (three) objects such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Entity": {
        "card": {
          "name": "Photos.no",
          "lastName": "Photos.caption2"
        },
        "Photos": {
          "*": {
            "Id": "Photos.no",
            "Caption": "Photos.caption2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2" // grouped by "Photos" which is grabbed after going the tree 3 leves up(&3) and binded as array by their respective indexes([&1] which yields 0,1,2) and thier key names(&2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir , for answering .I highly appreciate that.But i have one doubt what if in my input card has some more elements that we mapped to some other object ? Like 
"card":{
"cardnNo":"1234",
"cardAddress": "india",
"cardAddress1":"US"
}
NOW
in output the required is like
{
"card":{
"text":123
}
"address":[
above address
]
now i need that clubbed photoes array
}

Comment: Hi @SaurabhVerma , you^re welcome. We already restrict the keys to `name` and `lastName` considering both keys presented within the object, more keys won't matter unless them exist.

Comment: Actually i am very new to jolt transform . i was asking this .https://stackoverflow.com/q/74255796/20369933
thanks once again for answering .