# what will be the jolt transform for that?

Tags: java, json, jolt

I want the jolt transform for the given input . Your help in this is highly appreciated . thanks
i am providing the input and expected output.
in input json Photos array is dynamic in nature. Here it is 3 , it can be 3 or 4 or5 any .

INPUT JSON .

```json
{
  "Entity": {
    "card": {
     "cardNo":"123456789",
      "cardStatus":"10",
      "cardAddress":"UK",
      "cardAddress1":"US",
      "cardCity":"mk" ,
       "name": "RAM",
      "lastName": "ABU",
       "name1": "RAM1",
      "lastName1": "ABU1"
    },
    "Photos": [
      {
        "Id": "327703",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 1",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327703/photo.jpg"
      },
      {
        "Id": "327704",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 2",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327704/photo.jpg"
      },
      {
        "Id": "327704",
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 2",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327704/photo.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

OUTPUT GETTING after jolt transform

```json
{
  "tab": {
    "text": "123456789"
  },
  "address": [
    {
      "add": "UK",
      "add2": "US",
      "city": "mk"
    }
  ],
  "Photos": [
    {
      "no": "327703",
      "caption": "TEST>> photo 1"
    },
    {
      "no": "327704",
      "caption": "TEST>> photo 2"
    },
    {
      "no": "327704",
      "caption": "TEST>> photo 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

WHAT WILL BE THE CORRECT JOLT TRANSFORM FOR THIS?

jolt spec that i have used IS

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Entity": {
        "card": {
          "cardNo": "tab.text",
          "cardAddress": "address[0].add",
          "cardAddress1": "address[0].add2",
          "cardCity": "address[0].city",
          "name": "Photos[&1].no",
          "lastName": "Photos[&1].caption",
          "name1": "Photos[&1].no",
          "lastName1": "Photos[&1].caption"
        },
        "Photos": {
          "*": {
            "Id": "Photos[&1].no",
            "Caption": "Photos[&1].caption"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```json
{
  "tab": {
    "text": "123456789"
  },
  "address": [
    {
      "add": "UK",
      "add2": "US",
      "mk": "mk"
    }
  ],
  "Photos": [
    {
      "no": "RAM",
      "caption2": "ABU"
    },
    {
      "no": "RAM1",
      "caption2": "ABU1"
    },
    {
      "no": "327703",
      "caption2": "TEST>> photo 1"
    },
    {
      "no": "327704",
      "caption2": "TEST>> photo 2"
    },
    {
      "no": "327704",
      "caption2": "TEST>> photo 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am very new to jolt transform. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please post your java code for us to get a start reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two consecutive shift transformation specs, in the first determine the groupings as desired such as in the following

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Entity": {
        "card": {
          "cardNo": "tab.text",
          "cardAddress": "address[0].add",
          "cardAddress1": "address[0].add2",
          "cardC*": "address[0].mk",
          "nam*": "Photos.no",
          "lastNam*": "Photos.caption2"
        },
        "Photos": {
          "*": {
            "Id": "Photos.no",
            "Caption": "Photos.caption2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // "else" case --> the arrrays/objects/attributes other than "Photos"
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: sir , i can't explain how happy i am today . Thank you very much for solving above problem. Feeling great to interact with you sir .I am very new to jolt , can you please tell me  how i can learn this jolt transform so that i can do such complex by my own .
I am not able to understand this because jolt is very new to me .
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", 
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
what we have done here?

Comment: Very nice to hear such things @SaurabhVerma , you're welcome. I've explained that part within the previous answer( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74254055/i-have-an-issue-in-jolt-transformation-while-transforming-i-need-as-expected-ou ). There are such good blogs and links I can share :  [1](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases) , [2](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc) , [3](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt)

Comment: [4](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350) , [5](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi sir ,one quick question 
if i am adding constant in input json for eg
Entity": {
        "card": {
          "cardNo": "tab.text",
          "cardAddress": "address[0].add",
          "cardAddress1": "address[0].add2",
          "cardCity": "address[0].mk",
          "name": "Photos.no",
          "#plain": "Photos.caption2",
          "name1": "Photos.no",
          "#modify": "Photos.caption2"
        },
in this output is getting shuffle like photos array is coming up and address array is coming down. why?

Comment: {
  "Photos" : [ {
    "caption2" : "plain",
    "no" : "RAM"
  }, {
    "caption2" : "modify",
    "no" : "RAM1"
  }, {
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 1",
    "no" : "327703"
  }, {
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 2",
    "no" : "327704"
  }, {
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 2",
    "no" : "327704"
  } ],
  "tab" : {
    "text" : "123456789"
  },
  "address" : [ {
    "add" : "UK",
    "add2" : "US",
    "mk" : "mk"
  } ]
}

Comment: want this 
{
  "tab" : {
    "text" : "123456789"
  },
  "address" : [ {
    "add" : "UK",
    "add2" : "US",
    "mk" : "mk"
  } ],
  "Photos" : [ {
    "no" : "RAM",
    "caption2" : "plain"
  }, {
    "no" : "RAM1",
    "caption2" : "modify"
  }, {
    "no" : "327703",
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 1"
  }, {
    "no" : "327704",
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 2"
  }, {
    "no" : "327704",
    "caption2" : "TEST>> photo 2"
  } ]
}

Comment: Hi @SaurabhVerma , I don't know the reason, perhaps # sign has a precedence. You can fix the order by writing the attributes individually rather than using `"*":"&"` pair such as  the second spec to become `,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tab": "&",
      "address": "&",
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249186/discussion-between-saurabh-verma-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Comment: thanks ,
but in Photos array also caption2 is coming first than no but i want no and then caption 2.
thanks once again

Comment: Respected sir  @Barbaros
there is one problem coming in above jolt the problem is explained in details in 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74762976/20369933. can you please tell . thanks for giving time .