# jolt spec of the following input ? Thanks for the valueable time to answer

Tags: java, json, jolt

Here if Photos array in input JSON has multiple value then my current jolt spec is working fine but if Photos array in input JSON is empty like below and only Id1 and val field of input JSON IS MAPPED WITH  Photos of output json  then my second shift operation in jolt spec is failing. what will be the correct jolt spec that can handle both one value as well as multiple .
input json

```
{
  "Entity": {
    "card": {
      "cardNo": "123456789",
      "status": "10",
      "cardAddress": "UK",
      "cardAddress1": "US",
      "cardCity": "mk",
      "name": "RAM",
      "lastName": "ABU",
      "Id1": 23452540,
      "val": "uu",
      "bd2": "78",
      "bal": "ii"
    },
    "Photos": []
  }
}
```

output json

```
{
  "tab" : {
    "text" : "123456789"
  },
  "address" : [ {
    "add" : "UK",
    "add2" : "US",
    "mk" : "mk"
  } ],
  "status" : "10",
  "Photos" : [ {
    "no" : "23452540",
    "caption2" : "uu"
  }, {
    "no" : "78",
    "caption2" : "ii"
  } ]
}
```

jolt spec used

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Entity": {
        "card": {
          "cardNo": "tab.text",
          "status": "status",
          "cardAddress": "address[0].add",
          "cardAddress1": "address[0].add2",
          "cardC*": "address[0].mk",
          "Id1": "Photos.no",
          "val": "Photos.caption2",
          "bd2": "Photos.no",
          "bal": "Photos.caption2",
          "cf3": "Photos.no",
          "mal": "Photos.caption2",
          "lt4": "Photos.no",
          "tal": "Photos.caption2"
        },
        "Photos": {
          "*": {
            "Id": "Photos.no",
            "Caption": "Photos.caption2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tab": "&",
      "address": "&",
      "status": "&",
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "no": "=toString"
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

but if input is

```
{
  "Entity": {
    "card": {
      "cardNo": "123456789",
      "status": "10",
      "cardAddress": "UK",
      "cardAddress1": "US",
      "cardCity": "mk",
      "name": "RAM",
      "lastName": "ABU",
      "Id1": 23452540,
      "val": "uu"
    },
    "Photos": []
  }
}
```

then jolt spec is failing.
for above input need ouput

```
{
  "tab" : {
    "text" : "123456789"
  },
  "address" : [ {
    "add" : "UK",
    "add2" : "US",
    "mk" : "mk"
  } ],
  "status" : "10",
  "Photos" : [ {
    "no" : "23452540",
    "caption2" : "uu"
  } ]
}
```

Thanks for answer. What changes are required in above jolt spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it interestingly fails, might be a bug, I don't know. Rather you can try the following by adding `[]` to the end of the `Photos.no` and `Photos.caption2` identifiers in order to handle both cases :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Entity": {
        "card": {
          "cardNo": "tab.text",
          "status": "&",
          "cardAddress": "address[0].add",
          "cardAddress1": "address[0].add2",
          "cardC*": "address[0].mk",
          "Id1": "Photos.no[]",
          "val": "Photos.caption2[]",
          "bd2": "Photos.no[]",
          "bal": "Photos.caption2[]",
          "cf3": "Photos.no[]",
          "mal": "Photos.caption2[]",
          "lt4": "Photos.no[]",
          "tal": "Photos.caption2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#1].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Photos": {
        "*": {
          "no": "=toString"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: yes sir , this is now handling both cases. thanks.

Comment: you're welcome @SaurabhVerma nice to help

Comment: sir earlier was "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"   but now  "*": "&2[#1].&1"  . what is the difference now in this? earlier left hand side was @ now *? and right side also there is some differnce
thanks for answer.

Comment: Hi @SaurabhVerma , now you can even use `"Photos": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }` as in the original case or replacing that with  `"@": "&3[#2].&2"` as long as keep the `[]`s at the end of `Photos.no` and `Photos.caption2`. It's interesting that might be a bu, I don't know the reason.